# getting data from the database escaping slash using knex

Tags: node.js, json, knex.js

I use to get data from the database Knex. when receiving data knex escape slashing.

return this:

```
{"selector":"a[class=\\"xf-product-title__link js-product__title\\"]","site":"https:\\/\\/www.goo.com\\/catalog\\/kartinki\\/nasha/"}
```

need:

```
{"selector":"a[class=\"xf-product-title__link js-product__title\"]","site":"https://www.goo.com/catalog/kartinki/nasha/"}
```

how to fix this?

my code:

```
let result = new Promise(function (getRes,getErr) {
            knex.from('configs')
            .select('*')
            .where({id:id_config})
                .then((ans) => {
                    getRes(ans);
                }).catch((err) => { getErr(err) })
                .finally(() => {
                    knex.destroy();
                });
        });

        return await result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up javascript string literal representation and actual javascript obejct data and JSON string format data:

```
// store some jsonb data from DB to variable result
> result = null; knex.select(knex.raw(`'{"selector":"a[class=\\"xf-product-title__link js-product__title\\"]","site":"https://www.goo.com/catalog/kartinki/nasha/"}'::jsonb`)).then(res => result = res)

// data was returned from DB as javascript object
> result
[ { jsonb:
     { site: 'https://www.goo.com/catalog/kartinki/nasha/',
       selector: 'a[class="xf-product-title__link js-product__title"]' } } ]

// stringifying data to JSON string requires that " marks are escaped 
// but in javascript string literals \ escape mark shows as \\ because
// otherwise those could be mixed with \t or \n etc.   
> JSON.stringify(result)
'[{"jsonb":{"site":"https://www.goo.com/catalog/kartinki/nasha/","selector":"a[class=\\"xf-product-title__link js-product__title\\"]"}}]'

// however when javascript string literal is printed to console or written
// to file, those \\ marks are outputted as single backslashes
> console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
[{"jsonb":{"site":"https://www.goo.com/catalog/kartinki/nasha/","selector":"a[class=\"xf-product-title__link js-product__title\"]"}}]
```